# LibGDX draw() API inconsistency

Tags: java, libgdx

```
font.draw(batch, "Test", 50, 50);

batch.draw(tex, 100, 100);
(instead of)
tex.draw(batch, 100, 100);//Not valid for LibGDX
```

For drawing fonts, you pass batch (SpriteBatch) in as a parameter and draw() is a Font method. For drawing Texture (or TextureRegion) it's reversed. I know Texture has a draw() method of it's own for drawing a Pixmap on *itself*, but I would think renaming it to drawSelf() or drawPixmap() would allow Texture.draw() to draw itself, consistent with Font.draw().

Am I missing something obvious forcing it to be done this way?

Comment: Anyone care to say why this was downvoted?  Seems like a reasonable question still.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong when thinking about **Texture** as the same kind of object as **BitmapFont**. BitmapFont is an object with informations about text which is in it (so the text value, the glyphs textures, wrapping etc). Drawing text by BitmapFont object means **generating texture to render** (by setting it up from glyph textures) and then render it out to the screen.

You should think about BitmapFont as a kind of manager when Texture is rather like a set of pixels that **can be drawn** - of course it has some additional info more than just pixmap but it is ready to render.

Of course there is similarity in **draw** methods names but it is rather normal situation in object programming I guess - just don't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to think about it is that most types of drawable objects (such as BitmapFonts and Sprites) are complex. They handle the calculation of their own data, because they contain multiple sprites or size/orientation/color/position data, and so you pass the SpriteBatch into their `draw` methods so they can handle the transfer of data. It would not make sense (or be very object oriented) for SpriteBatch to know how to obtain the data of many different kinds of specific objects.

However, SpriteBatch does know how to handle the two simplest objects, Textures and TextureRegions. These simple objects do not contain any information about their size or orientation or color, so SpriteBatch can handle them and calculate the extra data if necessary (which is why SpriteBatch has so many overloaded `draw` methods).'

It does not make sense for a Texture to know how to draw itself with a SpriteBatch, because that is a specialized use case. Texture (and TextureRegion) is a generalized object that is intended to be used for all kinds of purposes (3D decals, wrapping a 3D model, custom implementations on a custom Mesh, etc.), so it would not be practical for it to know all the possible ways it could be drawn and implement them.

If you want Texture to be able to have its own `draw(batch)` method, you should subclass it to add that. (But there is already the Sprite class that has done this.)

One "gotcha" to watch out for is that Sprite extends TextureRegion, so you might accidentally call `spriteBatch.draw(sprite)` and wonder why your sprite is not sized or oriented correctly.